# What does '@reify' do and when should it be used?

Tags: python, pyramid

I saw it in the [Pyramid tutorial for UX design](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_tutorials/en/latest/humans/creatingux/step06/index.html). I couldn't make out much what this decorator is all about.

Sample code where I saw its usage.

```
def __init__(self, request):
    self.request = request
    renderer = get_renderer("templates/global_layout.pt")
    self.global_template = renderer.implementation().macros['layout']

@reify
def company_name(self):
    return COMPANY

@reify
def site_menu(self):
    new_menu = SITE_MENU[:]
    url = self.request.url
    for menu in new_menu:
        if menu['title'] == 'Home':
            menu['current'] = url.endswith('/')
        else:
            menu['current'] = url.endswith(menu['href'])
    return new_menu

@view_config(renderer="templates/index.pt")
def index_view(self):
    return {"page_title": "Home"}

@view_config(renderer="templates/about.pt", name="about.html")
def about_view(self):
    return {"page_title": "About"}
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

From the source code documentation:

> """ Put the result of a method which uses this (non-data)
>       descriptor decorator in the instance dict after the first call,
>       effectively replacing the decorator with an instance variable."""

A description from [from the fuzzy notepad blog](http://me.veekun.com/blog/2012/05/23/python-faq-descriptors/) sums it up nicely.

> It acts like @property, except that the function is only ever called
>   once; after that, the value is cached as a regular attribute. This
>   gives you lazy attribute creation on objects that are meant to be
>   immutable.

So in the code you posted, site_menu can be accesses like a cached property.

Answer (score 4):

According to the doc string ([source](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/blob/master/src/pyramid/decorator.py)):

```
""" Put the result of a method which uses this (non-data)
descriptor decorator in the instance dict after the first call,
effectively replacing the decorator with an instance variable."""
```