# @reify executes database queries every time called?

Tags: python, pyramid

Based on [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10776353/3295036) about reify,

> It acts like @property, except that the function is only ever called once; after that, the value is cached as a regular attribute. This gives you lazy attribute creation on objects that are meant to be immutable.

I have this custom reify class:

```
class reify(object):
    def __init__(self, wrapped):
        self.wrapped = wrapped

    def __get__(self, inst):
        if inst is None:
            return self
        val = self.wrapped(inst)
        setattr(inst, self.wrapped.__name__, val)
        return val
```

And it's used like:

```
@reify
def user_details(self, user_id):
    try:
        # function that executes db query, returns dict
        return user_details_from_id(self._dbconn, user_id)
    except Exception as e:
        pass
```

Clearly, we can use it just doing `name = self.user_details.get("name")`.

This works as expected, but not sure if this is caching the result or executing the query every time called, how can I confirm? I mean is this implementation correct? (don't have DB console)

Comment: Maybe replace the function that executes a db query by a function that prints something to the console?

Comment: yeah for sure it will do, but I think the real question is if this implementation is correct?

Comment: What I have suggested is a method to verify that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A signature like `def user_details(self, user_id)` has too many args to be supported by `@reify` or even `@property`. It should be `def user_details(self)`. The `reify` decorator will then modify the attribute `self.user_details` to return the same value for the duration of the instance. Note that it's not global, it's per-instance, because it uses `self`. To confirm it's caching, you can just put print statements in the `user_details` function to confirm it's only being invoked one time per instance.

Comment: yup, indeed I created a simple API server to fetch some user data, and it only makes one request, so this is good thanks for reply